# Mod_Rewrite to redirect `/about/` to `page.php?page=about`

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

I'm creating a website with Mod_Rewrite. At the moment all urls are redirected to the page name with `.php` on the end.

But `/about/` and `/photos/` should redirect to `page.php?page=about` and `page.php?page=photos` .

Is there a way to do this?

Current code:

```
RewriteEngine on RewriteBase /new/ 
RewriteRule ^about/$ /new/page.php?page=about [L] 
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ /new/$1.php [L] 
RewriteRule ^blog/([^/]*)/$ /new/blog.php?page=$1 [L] 
RewriteRule ^blog/post/([^/]*)/$ /post.php?post=$1 [L] 
RewriteRule ^blog/category/([^/]*)/$ /category.php?category=$1 [L]
```

Comment: how are the urls redirected? show the code you have, and show us what you tried and what goes wrong

Comment: This is the code: RewriteEngine on  
RewriteBase /new/
RewriteRule ^about/$ /new/page.php?page=about [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ /new/$1.php [L]
RewriteRule ^blog/([^/]*)/$ /new/blog.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^blog/post/([^/]*)/$ /post.php?post=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^blog/category/([^/]*)/$ /category.php?category=$1 [L]

Comment: Please add code like that in your question the next time. I've cleaned up everything a bit, but you might want to do this yourself the next time....

Comment: Thanks Nanne. I'm new so I'm just getting the hang of it all ! :)

Comment: Why do you need to repeat yourself, the filename is `page.php` why does the parameter name have to be `page` as well?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
RewriteRule ^blog(/?)$ /new/blog.php [L]
RewriteRule ^blog/([^/]*)(/?)$ /new/blog.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^blog/post/([^/]*)(/?)$ /post.php?post=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^blog/category/([^/]*)(/?)$ /category.php?category=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(?!blog)([^/]*)(/?)$ page.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks, but there is a blog at /blog/ so that would redirect to /page.php?page=blog which is invalid.

Comment: I've updated the rewrite. Let me know if this meets your needs.

Comment: /blog/ isn't working now and I have left the blog rewrites in.

Comment: I've updated it to include the necessary rules for everything to work. Let me know.

Comment: Nope, still not working. I think I am going to stick with the following code. `code`RewriteRule ^about/$ /new/page.php?page=about [L]
RewriteRule ^photos/$ /new/page.php?page=photos [L]
RewriteRule ^links/$ /new/page.php?page=links [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ /new/$1.php [L]
RewriteRule ^blog/([^/]*)/$ /new/blog.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^blog/post/([^/]*)/$ /post.php?post=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^blog/category/([^/]*)/$ /category.php?category=$1 [L]

Comment: I've made one last change if you'd like to try it. That approach will work if you want to hard code each rewrite manually. From my tests, it is working.

Comment: It then says that the query string 'page' isn't set. :(

Comment: Can you show me an example of what you're trying to go to? For example, is it something like http://yourserver/pagename/ ?

Comment: Alright. I've added some last directives which should prevent it from sending blog to the last rewrite rule if you are using an older version of apache. Sure thing.

Answer (score 0):

That's easy:

```
RewriteRule ^about/$ page.php?page=about 
RewriteRule ^photos/$ page.php?page=photos
```

Comment: Thanks for that Ron. I mean so that it is done dynamically so Mod_Rewrite can tell where to send it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /page.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

The [L] directive means "last" so it won't continue to apply any further rewriting rules if this one is matched.

The [QSA] directive allows you to attach query parameters to the rewritten address.

In the case of the blog rewrites all you need to do is have this rule last.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /new/$1.php 
    RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)/$ /new/blog.php?page=$1 [L] 
    RewriteRule ^blog/post/(.*)/$ /post.php?post=$1 [L] 
    RewriteRule ^blog/category/(.*)/$ /category.php?category=$1 [L]

    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /page.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks, but there is a blog at /blog/ so that would redirect to /page.php?page=blog which is invalid.

Comment: Careful this format means your links *have* to end with a slash.

Comment: It still doesn't work though whether there is a slash or not.

Comment: Please post your directory structure in your original question.

Comment: The 404 is probably resulting from RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /new/$1.php